# maven filtering replace multiple tokens during build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am able to replace the token with patter `${..}` under `src/main/resources`. I want to also replace the  tokens with pattern `@{}` under specific file 
`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/test.jsp` or directory `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content`.

I tried adding `<delimiter>@{test.version}</delimiter>` But I am not sure
how to make specific directory `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content`.

`test.version` will come at runtime like mvn clean install -Dtest.version=100

```
<build>
    <resources>
    <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource> 

    </resources>
 </build>



<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>xls</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
         <delimiters>
          <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
          <delimiter>@{*}</delimiter>
        </delimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the maven war plugin doesn't support custom delimiters: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-225 you'll have to use `${...}`.

Comment: If you like to have this feature make requests/votes on the issue @Tunaki has mentioned.

Comment: If you want to use a different delimiter than `${*}` have a look at my answer. But if you could use `${*}` in your JSP page as well, have a look at the answer from [Tunaki](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki). Which would be less fiddling.

Comment: Ironically, MWAR-225 was closed fixed on 15-Apr-16 as of maven-war-plugin 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder `@{*}` seems not to work with the replacer plugin.

As you anyway want to replace the placeholer by a value. You might use in the JSP files `#{test.version}` instead. For the filtering you can define different directories. See the snippet below.

Assuming following structure.

```
pom.xml
src/main/resources/hello.txt
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/test.jsp
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sub.optimal.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>superapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>superapp</name>

    <properties>
        <test.version>world</test.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>../webapp/WEB-INF/content</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>      
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                        <delimiter>#{*}</delimiter>
                        <!-- this delimiter is not recognized -->
                        <delimiter>@{*}</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>target/webapp</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**hello.txt**

```
Hello $ ${test.version} txt
Hello # #{test.version} txt
Hello @ @{test.version} txt
```

**test.jsp**

```
Hello $ ${test.version} jsp
Hello # #{test.version} jsp
Hello @ @{test.version} jsp
```

build the WAR file

```
mvn clean package
```

output

```
> jar tf superapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/content/
WEB-INF/classes/hello.txt
WEB-INF/content/test.jsp
WEB-INF/web.xml
META-INF/maven/sub.optimal.example/superapp/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/sub.optimal.example/superapp/pom.properties

# copy the file into a temp directory and extract it
# jar xf superapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war

>cat WEB-INF/classes/hello.txt
Hello $ world txt
Hello # world txt
Hello @ @{test.version} txt

>cat WEB-INF/content/test.jsp
Hello $ world jsp
Hello # world jsp
Hello @ @{test.version} jsp
```

The example only shows the idea and might need some tweaks to exclude files, file locations, and so on.

Comment: Except this won't work when building the real WAR. The JSP isn't supposed to go under `target/classes`.

Comment: @Tunaki See my updated example. About the location of the file `The example only shows the idea and might need some tweaks ...` I updated this part to include the file location as well.

Comment: Yes well it did need a lot of tweaks :) but now it'll work indeed, thanks for updating!

Comment: Thanks a lot SubOptimal for such a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

The file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content/test.jsp` is a web resource: it is under `src/main/webapp` so it is handled by the [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and not the `maven-resources-plugin`.

You can also [filter web resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) with this plugin, with the help of the `filtering` attribute. You could have the following configuration to filter all web resources under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content`:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you only want to filter `test.jsp`, you can also restrict this by including only this file, and have

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content</directory>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
  <includes>
    <include>test.jsp</include>
  </includes>
</resource>
```

However, you cannot currently set custom delimiters with this plugin (issue [MWAR-225](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-225) and unresolved), so you will have to stick to the default ones, [which are](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/) `${...}` and `@...@` (but not `@{...}`).

Comment: Hum why downvote? It answers the question (there's a bug so OP can't do what they want) so I offer alternative. There's no duplicate mentioning that particular maven-war-plugin issue. And I'm fairly sure it works since I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way to do it:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <execution>
            <id>Filter specific resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                    [Place to put filtered result]
                </outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>
                            src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/content
                        </directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <delimiters>
                    <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                    <delimiter>@{*}</delimiter>
                </delimiters>
                <!--<useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>-->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: No, this won't work. A JSP isn't a project resource. It is a web resources. It shouldn't be output to `target/classes`.

Comment: With the tag `outputDirectory` one can specify the location where it should be put.

Comment: Yes, and what would that be? Take a look at SubOptimal's answer. It isn't straightforward at all...